# Antonyms of "meliorism"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

What are the near antonyms of *meliorism*?

I think the antonym will oppose the belief that the world can be made better by human effort. It can be a disbelief in efforts or humanity, despondency of some sort and likewise.

Is there a word suitable as an antonym to *meliorism*?

Comment: ***cynicism.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Optimism*, *meliorism*, *pejorism*, and *pessimism* are from Latin *optimus*, *melior*, *peior*, and *pessimus*, respectively, meaning "best", "better", "worse", and "worst".

From that grouping, the closest antonym is *pejorism* (meaning "the belief that the world is becoming worse"), but the more-familiar *pessimism* will probably suffice for most purposes.

Comment: *Bonus*! **Pejorism**.  *pejorist*: One who believes that the world is getting worse *The pejorist believes that the world isn't getting any better.* http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pejorist

Comment: Cite sources of information in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is no precise antonym for *meliorism*. I think **[negativism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/negativism)**  may come close to it:

> - a negative or pessimistic attitude.
> - Psychology . a tendency to resist external commands, suggestions, or expectations, or internal stimuli, as hunger, by doing nothing or something contrary or unrelated to the stimulus.
> - any system of negative philosophy, as agnosticism or skepticism.