# Antonyms of “intersection ”

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

There are two places you're most likely to find intersections: in math class([Discrete Math Concept](http://math.tutorcircle.com/discrete-math/)) and in traffic. In math, an intersection is the spot where two lines cross. Those lines share this common point. The center of the letter X is an intersection. The same is true for streets.

What are the near antonyms of intersection for a math and traffic concepts?

I think the antonym will describe something "out of intersection" or those not intersect with the referenced "thing".

Is there a word suitable as an antonym to intersection ?

The closest word I found was "disjoint", "disjointed".

PS:

"Antonyms are only significant when it is a binary word. Antonym is a binary concept. And two non-intersecting lines are parallel only in Euclidean plane geometry; not in solid geometry, and not in non-Euclidean geometry. There is no simple antonym without an equally simple context, which must be presupposed."

Yes, it seems even something dummy(to not say stupid) try to get a word(or words) with the opposite meaning of a non-binary word, who would want to set a non-apple?

The objective of my question is to find some word to clear (self explanatory) give a name for a program method to get an object that doesn't intersect this thing.

I'm just looking forward to find another word to represent "non-intersection".

Comment: Antonyms are only meaningful when there is a single dimension for contrast, as in _cold/hot_, where temperature is the only relevant variable, and the antonyms have opposite values for it. Which dimension of _intersection_ do you want to reverse its sign?

Comment: I don't get the connection of the antonym-of-intersection and the-inability-for-humanity-to-improve-the-world. Can you elaborate on that metaphor?

Comment: @JohnLawler I understand that antonyms are more significant when it is a binary word, but I think the antonym will describe something "out of intersection" or those not intersect with the referenced "thing".

Comment: @DanBron Please ignore that sentence, I have no idea who this phrase come to my question.

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho I see. Did you happen to copy/paste from [antonyms of "meliorism"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178540/antonyms-of-meliorism) as a template for asking about antonyms generally?

Comment: @DanBron yes, but your commentary is not relevant  or helpful for this question. But thanks for bring me attention for that.

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho Well, you could have forestalled it by simply telling me what happened, rather than saying you don't know where it came from.

Comment: @DanBron Certainly, but I was avoiding a kind of chat here and not take off the focus of my question.
Please accept my sincere apologies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43424/discussion-between-leonancarvalho-and-dan-bron).

Comment: This is yet another question asking for an antonym of a non-binary concept. One might as well ask what the opposite of an apple is. It's a non-apple. Just like you're asking about a non-intersection. There are hundreds, if not thousands, of things one can dream up that are not intersections. Non of these makes someone think about intersections, in the sense that they think "it's the opposite of an intersection". In mathematics, two lines that do not intersect are by definition _parallel_. Two objects that do not intersect are _non-intersecting_.  As for roads, there simply is no intersection.

Comment: Antonyms are **only** significant when it is a binary word. _Antonym_ is a binary concept. And two non-intersecting lines are parallel only in Euclidean plane geometry; not in solid geometry, and not in non-Euclidean geometry. There is no simple antonym without an equally simple context, which must be presupposed.

Comment: Yes, it seems even something dummy(to not say stupid) try to get a word(or words) with the opposite meaning of a non-binary word, who would want to set a non-apple?

The closest word I found was "disjoint", "disjointed", what your opinion about these words?

The objective of my question is to find some word to clear (self explanatory) give a name for a program method to get an object that doesn't intersect this thing.

Comment: Both asking for opinions and naming requests are off-topic by definition of the help center. For a word request there is no example sentence. Thus I am voting to close.

Comment: Well, not hurt to try, I believe this site is to this kind of things, questions & answers. If Moderators think it should be a offtopic or something else ok, but please don't downvote for that just because you think it's a invalid question, because don't. I do not like to see this issue simply sinking. I think it could be educational to others like was to me.

I'm just looking forward to find another word to represent "non-intersection"

Comment: Please don't post [identical questions](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/98530/antonyms-of-intersection) on two sites. It's [not allowed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) unless you are specifically gearing the questions for the audience of the site. These two questions are verbatim.

Comment: *disjunction* : "a lack of connection between things that are related or should be connected" –MW

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because naming requests are off-topic.

Comment: @Catija on ALL my intention was "Word choice and usage", same where on english stackexchange, but with different approach, since here have found simmilar questions.

Comment: Not sure why the question is off-topic. The question is valid to me in terms of "what's a thing called in English?". He's asking exactly what I google for. Since when StackExchange is too strict on defining terms and question title? He doesn't know what he doesn't know. Me either. Not everyone is native English speaker to ask exactly what's supposed to be. Could you guys be less strict on Q&A? You guys (mods) are new or gen Z?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a single word, but in mathematics, conceptually you are after the ***symmetric difference***:

> In mathematics, the **symmetric difference**, also known as the disjunctive union, of two sets is the set of elements which are in either of the sets and not in their intersection.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference)</sub>

The reference article provides a nice illustration:

[image]

For traffic or roads, I thought about ***roundabout***, which is a way to get to a cross street without a direct intersection, or a ***track***, which is a closed circuit used for racing, thus theoretically lacks an intersection.